# Extracting Keys From Redis

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I use this following code to extract all of the Keys start with "NAME:" and it return only over 5,000 records (There is over 60,000 keys in my index). Can anyone explain why it is happening or how can I extract  all of the keys from Redis Database.

```
jedis.select(3);

    Set<String> names=jedis.keys("NAME:*");

    Iterator<String> it = names.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String s = it.next();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure all your keys starts with "NAME:"? I think keys command is case sensitive, so if you have "name:" or "Name:" it won't match.

Comment: Thanks for Reply. Yes, I'm Sure All my Keys Start with "NAME:". And also I manually extract Keys start with "NAME:" and there is more than 60,000 result.

Comment: that sounds really strange, are all keys in the DB you selected? Did you use the jedis String api, or byte[] to write the keys? i used the keys command in a few scenarios an never had any problems

Comment: did you get an answer to this by any chance?

Comment: from redis documentation, they don't recommend to use `KEYS` command on production environement. so you can use `SCAN` instead. _Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider using SCAN or sets._

Answer (score 4):

When Redis server store many record, using `jedis.keys()` command can make it over-processing. Thus, result in it stop when the task is un-done. 
Instead of it, you use `jedis.hscan()` so as to avoid above problem.

```
ScanParams scanParam = new ScanParams();
String cursor = "0";
int i = 0;
scanParam.match(prefix + "*");
scanParam.count(50000); // 2000 or 30000 depend on your
do {
ScanResult<Map.Entry<String, String>> hscan = jedis.hscan(key, cursor, scanParam);

// any code here
//
//

// check cursor 
cursor = hscan.getStringCursor();
} while("0".equals(cursor));
```

It work well in your case.

Comment: Super old post, but I got here looking for validation of the scan logic.  Per the docs (https://redis.io/commands/scan#scan-basic-usage), "An iteration starts when the cursor is set to 0, and terminates when the cursor returned by the server is 0".  So, the do/while should continue so long as the cursor does NOT equal "0".  It should be do { ... } while (!"0".equals(cursor));

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `keys` method for normal Redis usage as stated in the JavaDoc below.

http://javadox.com/redis.clients/jedis/2.2.0/redis/clients/jedis/Jedis.html#keys(java.lang.String)

Instead consider using Redis sets like this.

```
final Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");
jedis.sadd("setName", "someValue");
jedis.smembers("setName");
jedis.close();
```

Answer (score -3):

Try without NAME in keys search pattern.

```
        Set<String> names = jedis.keys("*");

        java.util.Iterator<String> it = names.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            String s = it.next();
            System.out.println(s + " : " + jedis.get(s));
        }
```

Comment: It will work if you have small number of keys in Redis. It's not good practice to fetch all keys using '*', It will overhead to application if you have huge keys in Redis. To avoid overhead issue we always can store keys using some prefix like ID_ (ID_607890). When we want to fetch ID related keys we can use ID_ as prefix to fetch. Also we can prefer to fetch keys batch wise from Redis.